# Can I somehow iterate through collection with definite initial and end index using standard JSTL? Or should I create a custom jstl tag?

Tags: java, jsp, collections, jstl, iteration

I need to create a pagination on jsp page for a list of objects, so I need to iterate only through a range of indexes.

Comment: Would you, please, add some code to illustrate what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: -1; this question does not show **any** research effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose

```
class Person {
  int age;
  String name;
}
```

and personList is a list of persons. then you can iterate like this...

```
<c:forEach var="person" items="${personList}" varStatus="status">
         <c:if test="${status.index >= startIndex && status.index < endIndex}">      
             ${person}
         </c:if>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not the thing I need. I mean, I need something like for(int i = startPos; i < endPos; ++i) out(personList.get(i);

Comment: updated answer AS PER COMMENT